Console screen import/export error when using freopen
Can anyone tell me that when using freopen, sometimes when I call new functions using input and output commands on the console screen, it doesn't work? When running, it still works and still processes [textthe code normally or uses the process of reading and writing normal file types, but cout on the screen and cin from the keyboard will not be displayed but will just be skipped and completed. I tried cin, suspend the system but it still doesn't stop.
Hope everyone can tell me where I'm wrong? Thanks a lot
